# Preventing CMake-generated makefile for optional-header-only library from compiling source files in header-only mode

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, header-files, header-only

I have a library that can both be used as an header-only library and as a traditional library. To enable this optional-header-only functionality, the library includes `.cpp` source files if compiled in header-only mode. Example:

```
// Vector.hpp
// (Module file), intended to be included manually by the user
#ifndef LIBRARY_MODULE_VECTOR
#define LIBRARY_MODULE_VECTOR

#include "Library/Vector/Inc/Vector2.hpp"
#include "Library/Vector/Inc/Vector3.hpp"
#include "Library/Vector/Inc/VectorUtils.hpp"

#if defined(LIBRARY_HEADERONLY)
    #include "Library/Vector/Src/Vector2.cpp"
    #include "Library/Vector/Src/Vector3.cpp"
    #include "Library/Vector/Src/VectorUtils.cpp"
#endif

#endif
```

When the user includes `Vector.hpp` in one of his/her projects, if `LIBRARY_HEADERONLY` is defined, the implementation source files will be included right after the header files. Careful usage of the `inline` keyword is applied to avoid multiple definitions.

If `LIBRARY_HEADERONLY` is undefined, the `.cpp` files will be compiled and the library will have to be linked.

---

My build system of choice is **CMake**.

Using a CMake flag, the user can define or undefine `LIBRARY_HEADERONLY`.

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is similar to this:

```
# (not shown) set flag and cache variables...

# Include library directory
include_directories("./${INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}")

# Glob all library header/source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_LIST "${INC_DIR}/*" "${SRC_DIR}/*")

# (Not shown) Check if header-only mode is enabled
# (from now on we assume header-only mode is enabled and that
# LIBRARY_HEADERONLY is defined)

# Use all source/header files as a library target
add_library(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET STATIC ${SRC_LIST})
set_target_properties(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
install(DIRECTORY ${INC_DIR} DESTINATION .)
```

---

Unfortunately, the CMake-generated makefile **always** compiles the `.cpp` files, even when header-only mode is enabled and the target is `HEADER_ONLY_TARGET`.

**How can I prevent the CMake-generated makefile from compiling the source files in header-only mode?**

Note that **IDEs reliant on CMake-generated output, such as Qt Creator, should display both the header and source files** as part of the project.

If I don't glob any source file, but only the `.hpp` header files, CMake will complain that no source files were selected for a library target, and IDEs that rely on CMake files will not display any item.

Comment: If you are using latest CMake, you can use "Interface Libraries" : http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the source files' `HEADER_FILE_ONLY` property to prevent them from building, e.g.:

```
if (LIBRARY_HEADERONLY)
    set_source_files_properties(${SRC_LIST} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY 1)
    ...
endif()
```

Also see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/HEADER_FILE_ONLY.html).

Comment: Seems to work properly! The IDE loads all files and it seems that all files are installed correctly. Nothing is compiled upon execution of the `makefile`. I play around with it some more but it seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Create_Header_Only)
    add_library(TargetName INTERFACE)
    # Clients will build with -DLIBRARY_HEADERONLY
    target_compile_definitions(TargetName INTERFACE LIBRARY_HEADERONLY)
else()
    add_library(TargetName STATIC thesource.cpp)
endif()

# Clients will build with -Iinclude
target_include_directories(TargetName INTERFACE include)
```

Client code just does:

```
add_executable(mine main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mine TargetName)
```

See also *[Transitive Usage Requirements](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements)* and all the rest of those CMake manuals regarding creating packages, etc.

An approach of defining all library types and letting the consumer choose between them is outlined in:

*[Opt-in header-only libraries with CMake](https://steveire.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/opt-in-header-only-libraries-with-cmake/)*

Something like:

```
add_library(lib_shared SHARED ...)
add_library(lib_shared STATIC ...)
add_library(lib_iface INTERFACE)
```

So that the consumer makes the choice of which to link to:

```
# target_link_libraries(consumer lib_static)
# target_link_libraries(consumer lib_shared)
target_link_libraries(consumer lib_iface)
```

Comment: I've tried this solution, but IDEs that rely on CMakeFiles output do not work correctly. Since I cannot specify source/header files for `INTERFACE` libraries the IDE does not detect any file in the CMake project.

Comment: Your comment is not very clear, but if you have encountered a bug please file a good report at http://public.kitware.com/Bug

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I don't think this is a CMake bug. I'm using QTCreator as my IDE, and it automatically detects files belonging to a project after running CMake. The files detected by QTCreators are the files that are set in SRC_LIST after calling add_library. When using the INTERFACE option, there is no list of files, and QTCreator detects no files. What I'm looking for is a way to tell the IDE and CMake that all files (both header and source) belong to the project, but that the source files should only be compiled if the library is being used in non-header only mode

Comment: You can probably add the headers to the INTERFACE library with target_sources INTERFACE http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_sources.html .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not separate the GLOB for HEADERS and SRC files? You could add a dummy.cpp (a empty .cpp file) for creating header-only libraries. I mean:

```
# Glob all library header files
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_ONLY_LIST "${INC_DIR}/*.hpp")

# Glob all library src files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_ONLY_LIST "${SRC_DIR}/*.cpp")

# Check if LIBRARY_HEADERONLY is defined, so you can filter the target files
if(LIBRARY_HEADERONLY)
    set(SRC_LIST ${HEADER_ONLY_LIST} dummy.cpp) # I don't know if it's needed to add a dummy.cpp file with your set_target_properties(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET ...)
else()
    set(SRC_LIST ${HEADER_ONLY_LIST} ${SRC_ONLY_LIST})
endif(LIBRARY_HEADERONLY)

# Use all source/header files as a library target
add_library(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET STATIC ${SRC_LIST})
set_target_properties(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
install(DIRECTORY ${INC_DIR} DESTINATION .)
```

Anyway, CMake 3.X.X gives you the chance for creating [INTERFACE libraries (header-only ones)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html).

Comment: I've tried the `INTERFACE` solution (see the comment to question below) and the `dummy.cpp` solution. The dummy solution doesn't work for IDEs that rely on CMakeFiles-generated makefiles. The only "loaded" files in the IDE are the .hpp files and the dummy file.